# Pass inherited Interface to a method

Tags: c#, interface

I'm having the following interfaces:

```
public interface IBase
{
    int id1 { get; set; }
}

public interface IDerived : IBase
{
    int id2 { get; set; }
}
```

And the following (sample) program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<IDerived> derived = null;
        Check(derived);
    }

    static void Check(IList<IBase> base)
    {
    }
}
```

I'm getting this compliation error:
cannot convert from '`System.Collections.Generic.IList<IDerived>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.IList<IBase>`'

If I'm trying to pass only one instance, and not a list, it's working, so what am I missing here?

Thanks,

Comment: Isn't `base` a reserved keyword in c#?

Comment: Not a week goes by on SO where someone doesn't ask a question about covariance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to cast the IList items to IBase. Here's an example using Linq extensions:

```
Check(derived.Cast<IBase>());
```

Comment: This seems to work only if I change the "Check" method parameter to IEnumerable<> instead of IList<> (which seems to be a similar issue to the one discussed here...IList<> implements IEnumerable<>).

Comment: Sorry, still early in the morning...

Adding ToList() fixed the problem:
Check(derived.Cast<IBase>().ToList());

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is due to a lack of covariance on interfaces types in C# 3, C# 4 will allow you to specify covariance and contravariance on interfaces types.

Unfortunately this is one of those things that just doesn't work the way you think it should in C# 3.

Answer (score 2):

An instance of `IList<IDerived>` is not an instance of `IList<IBase>`.  For one thing, you can't call `.Add(new ConcreteBase())` on it. (where `ConcreteBase` implements `IBase`)

Comment: calling .Add(new ConcreteBase()) is not the same as passing a "Derived Instance" using a "Base Type" reference.

Answer (score 0):

And yet this would work...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<IDerived> derived = null;
        Check(derived.ToArray());
    }

    static void Check(IBase[] asdf)
    {
    }
```

One of several reasons I prefer the raw array [] or IEnumerable<> for interfaces both on arguments and return values.  But if you prefer using List/IList you can still do the following:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<IDerived> derived = null;
        Check(derived);
    }

    static void Check<T>(IList<T> asdf) where T : IBase
    {
    }
```